# Excel formula - Access cell based on concatenated index?

Tags: excel, indexing, concatenation, formula

Is there any way to use a formula to indicate which cell you are trying to access in Excel? For example, if I want to access cell B7, is there any way to write this as B(3+4)?

I am using a MATCH formula to find where a value exists in the sheet. Based on that formula, I am selecting certain cells around that value. But I can't find a way to "concatenate" a row number I found using a formula with the specified column number.

Comment: `=index(B:B, (3+4))`

Comment: Could you paste some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to return "B7" in a formula:

```
=ADDRESS((3+4),2,4)
```

If you're trying to do something in the form of a backwards VLOOKUP, you can use a combination of INDEX and MATCH, such as:

```
=INDEX(A:D,MATCH(F1,B:B,0),1)
```

That would look for the value in cell "F1" within column B and return the corresponding value in column A.

Also, if you are only looking to bring in the row number that the MATCH formula returns, then you just need to do:

```
="B"&MATCH(xx,xx,xx)
```

Since MATCH returns the row number.

Without seeing an example of what it is you're working with and trying to do, this is the best I can offer.  I would have put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation points yet :\

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

More broadly than just using INDEX/MATCH (which is often preferable), you can use the INDIRECT function to dynamically tell Excel which cell to point to.

For example:

```
=INDIRECT("B"&3+4)
```

Will resolve to INDIRECT("B7"), and will show the value currently in the B7 cell. Note that INDIRECT is an expensive function, as Excel must recalculate it whenever anything in the workbook updates, because it can't tell what its precedents are.